# How to create a File from byte array and add it to the gallery in android

Tags: java, android, file

**I have a function::**

```
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    //Creating the Image file here
    }



 public static void addImageToGallery(final String filePath, final Context context) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filePath);

        context.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    }
```

---

1. How to create a file from `data` properly.
2. I want to create a file and get the absolute path of the file
3. Finally I want to add the image into the gallery, for which I already have the function

Comment: see `MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage()`

Comment: did you see its javadocs: "Insert an image and create a thumbnail for it. Returns The URL to the newly created image, or null if the image failed to be stored for any reason." ?

Comment: How to create thumbnail ?

Comment: use `MediaStore.Images.Media#insertImage()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this..

```
private void createFile(byte[] fileData) {
            try {
                //Create directory..
                File root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + "/YOUR_FOLDER_NAME");
                File dir = new File(root + File.separator);
                if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();

                //Create file..
                File file = new File(root + File.separator + "YOUR_IMAGE_NAME");
                file.createNewFile();

                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                out.write(fileData);
                out.close();

            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating file from byte array:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("pathname");
fos.write(myByteArray);
fos.close();
```

or use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeByteArrayToFile%28java.io.File,%20byte%5B%5D%29) ([home](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)):

```
FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("pathname"), myByteArray)
```